# Agregar Menu no deja ver mis fragments Android

Tags: java, android

estoy empezando con fragments y tengo una pequeña app con 2 fragments tipo tabs , quise agregarle un menu lateral el cual tambien pude hacerlo andar correctamente , el error viene a la hora de querer tener las 2 cosas , si pongo el menu los fragments no aparecen , y si saco el menu si aparecen los fragments , dejo un poco mi clase de main ,

```
`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);


        Toolbar mToolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.bringToFront();
        drawer.requestLayout();
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.requestLayout();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);




    }`

// Métodos de la interfaz ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

// Métodos de la interfaz ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    /**
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

}
     */

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment tabFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tabFragment = new TabAFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                tabFragment = new TabBFragment();
                break;
        }
        return tabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        String section = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                section =  "Servicio en Curso";
                break;
            case 1:
                section = "Ficha Técnica";
                break;
        }
        return section;
    }
}
```

Mi vista

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            android:background="@color/white"
            />



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/black"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/audilogo"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

si comento la parte del menu los fragments si aparecen correctamente , si dejo el menu aparece el menu correctamente pero no los fragments desde ya gracias

Comment: Poruqe quieres hacer eso? estos metodos de navegacion se usan para casos diferentes cada uno de ellos. No veo un caso viable para usarlos. En caso de que lo requieras, lo que debes hacer es encapsular tus tabs en un solo fragments, debido a que el navigation drawer implementa una vista a base de fragments. Te esta quitando tus tabas porque desplaza los tabs y no los deja desplegar en pantalla.

Comment: en si idea es poder quedarme con los 2 tabs  y tambien quiero un menu lateral , pero en realidad los 2 tabs estan en un appbarlayout y el menu lateral lo tengo en otro control ?

Comment: No no. Seria que encapsularas toda la logica de los tabs en un fragment y dentro de tu navigation View hagas uso de dicho fragment con la logica de los tabs. El navigationView se encargara de hacer el control de todos los fragments incluyendo el fragment que incluye los tabs

Comment: Por ende el fragment de los tabs debe encapsular tambien los fragments relacionados con sus tabs.

Comment: bien la verdad no te entendi ni la mitad pero voy a intentar guiarme por esto y ver que sucede

Comment: jajajaj es un poco complicado al arrancar, por eso te recomiendo que uses un solo criterio de navegacion. se te puede complicar mucho el codigo.

Comment: Pude resolverlo con esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523188/coordinatorlayout-appbarlayout-navigationdrawer